# Strange Error With Scala Generics Implementation

Tags: scala

I have the following trait:

```
trait SomeTrait {
  def doSomething[V](msg: Message[V]): Message[V]
}
```

The Message[V] is a case class as below:

```
case class Message[V](elems: Map[String, V])
```

I now have a method that calls the doSomething method as below:

```
  val someWork = new SomeTrait {
    override def doSomething[Int](msg: Message[Int]): Message[Int] = {
      msg.copy(elems = msg.elems.map {
        case (k, v) => (k, v + 1) // It fails here!!!
      })
    }
  }
```

I get a strange compiler error saying that:

```
Error:(16, 32) type mismatch;
 found   : Int(1)
 required: String
Error occurred in an application involving default arguments.
        case (k, v) => (k, v + 1)
```

Was I stupid somewhere?

Comment: Note: `+` is exceptionally bad in producing error messages because of default implicit conversion of anything to `String`. When you replace it with `*`, you will get more sensible error: value * is not a member of type parameter Int.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beware: your `Int` is not scala `Int`. You are hiding the Scala `Int` behind a generic type name - what you write looks like a template specialization in C++, but generics do not work this way in Scala. You will get the same error when you replace `[Int]` with `[XXX]` in your code.

You cannot change the type signature when override the method. As the trait promises you accept any type `V` without any constraints, the implementation needs to satisfy this promise.

C++-like specialization can be achieved using [type classes](http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2013/02/06/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-12-type-classes.html) - you extend your contract by promising you will provide the specialized implementations as needed:

```
case class Message[V](elems: Map[String, V])

trait SomeTrait {
  def doSomething[V: MapValue](msg: Message[V])
}

trait MapValue[V] {
  def map(v: V): V
}

implicit object MapValueInt extends MapValue[Int] {
  def map(v: Int) = v + 1
}

val someWork = new SomeTrait {
  override def doSomething[X: MapValue](msg: Message[X]) = {
    val evidence = implicitly[MapValue[X]]
    msg.elems.map {
      case (k, v) => k -> evidence.map(v)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What @Suma said ... You could also parametrize the trait instead of the method in this case. It is less generic, but a bit simpler:

```
trait SomeTrait[V] {
  def doSomething(msg: Message[V]): Message[V]
}

val someWork = new SomeTrait[Int] {
  def doSomething(msg: Message[Int]) = msg.copy(msg.elems.mapValues(_ + 1) 
}
```

Comment: The difference is that in one case you have a trait with a parameterized method, and in the other case the trait itself is parameterized, so, once you create the instance, the type of the method is known. Not sure what trips you up. Perhaps, you could elaborate ...